# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome: How to fix nausea/headaches with LG Gaming Monitor (LG 32GK850G-B 144hz)

Tags: nvidia, monitor, lg

After buying this monitor and plugging it in, I started having a slow sense of nausea increasingly. But this monitor [is certified flicker free](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/reviews/lg_32gk850g.htm). So I stopped using it and then tried the next day. I had the same result the next day, so I knew something was up.

Then to my surprise, when I switched over to Windows with the latest graphics driver, it worked fine and could tell the difference immediately. Apparently nVidia had issued a fix via a graphics drivers update (it's a G-Sync monitor so it has a nVidia controller inside the monitor)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I updated via GeForce Experience, but on Ubuntu I used gnome-terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt search nvidia
sudo apt install <latest drivers>
```

For me that was:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-396
```

*NOTE: YOU MUST REBOOT FOR IT TO TAKE EFFECT*

Double check you're on the right driver by opening `nvidia-settings` from terminal (if it throws an error, saying you can't detect the display it's due to being on the X driver (See: `Software Updates > Additional Drivers` to see all drivers on your system)

I also set the monitor settings to `Reader Mode` on Ubuntu (via the physical buttons), but on Windows when gaming I don't, not sure why that seems to help.

Note: It's a big monitor so you can still get motion sickness caused nausea from FPS games or games with a lot of camera movement, so to fix that:

- push the monitor far away from you
- or play the game in 'Windowed' mode so the screen is tiny.

  That's not the monitor's fault, that's just your brain trying to make sense of all the movement.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution I found was to switch to Compiz (after running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to get `nvidia-390` and turning off OpenGL flipping in `nvidia-settings`)

Comment: I theorize it may have simply lowered the refresh rate from 144hz to 60hz with this driver??